# Does Swagger UI support @PathVariable binding?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Currently when I'm testing the Swagger UI for a **GET** request that binds the "id" path variable to a data object, the dataType of the "id" field is Model, instead of a Long.

For instance, here is the method in the RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = GET)
    public AwardVO getAwardById(@PathVariable("id") Award award) {
        LOG.info("inside the get award method: "+award);
        if (award == null) {
            throw new AwardNotFoundException();
        }

        return new AwardVO(award);
    }
```

Here is the resulting documentation:

[image: swagger ui example]

So when I pass a Long to the input field, I don't receive the desired record.  Is this type of binding supported in Swagger, or do I need to just need to do a lookup for the record and pass the PathVariable as a Long?

**Version of Swagger:** compile "com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:0.9.5"

**SwaggerConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig).apiInfo(
                apiInfo())
                .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
                .includePatterns("/v1/.*", "/register/.*");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("API", "API",
                "API terms of service", "email@gmail.com",
                "API Licence Type", "API License URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you produce your Swagger documentation?

Comment: @Ron I added some additional info about the setup. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it should work as expected if you replace  `@PathVariable` with `@ModelAttribute`.

To answer your question, yes it does support  `@PathVariable`, but only primitives or strings.